# Filtering a file based on values from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, filter

I have two files

file1:

```
U   20      100     1_A         1_A
U   14      200     1_B         1_B
U   14      300     1_C         1_C
```

file2:

```
D   12  90      1_A     1_A
D   15  97      1_A     1_A
D   16  99.5    1_A     1_A
D   9   111     1_A     1_A
D   71  200     1_B     1_B
D   88  198     1_B     1_B
D   12  210     1_B     1_B
D   11  211     1_B     1_B
D   9   266     1_C     1_C
D   18  278     1_C     1_C
D   20  300.5   1_C     1_C
D   17  300     1_C     1_C
```

The 4th column includes the same values in both files (the 5th column too which is the same as the 4th) but in file1 every value appears only once meanwhile in file2 each value is present multiple times with differences in the 2nd and 3rd column.

I would like to get the lines from file2 where the 3rd column's value is within the range of ±1 of the corresponding line from file2 (where the 4th column's values are the same).

Expecting output:

```
D   16   99.5       1_A
D   71   200        1_B     
D   20   300.5      1_C     
D    17  300        1_C
```

tried using this:

```
while read c1 c2 c3 c4 
do
awk '{if ( a = $4  &&  b < $3+1 && b > $3-1 ) print $1 "    " $2 "  " $3 "  " $5 }' a="$c4" b="$c3"  file2.txt > output.txt
done < file1.tx
```

and I got this output:

```
D   20  300.5   1_C
D   17  300     1_C
```

so it's only using the b value from the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) without need of a shell-loop:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ col4[$4]=$3; next }
  (-1< col4[$4]-$3 && col4[$4]-$3 <1) { print $1, $2, $3, $5 }' file1 file2
```

you should check if the substraction result of two numbers are within (-1,1) exclusively rather than adding ±1 to third column value and comparing with its pair.

If you want differences within [-1,1] inclusively:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ col4[$4]=$3; next }
  (-1<= col4[$4]-$3 && col4[$4]-$3 <=1) { print $1, $2, $3, $5 }' file1 file2
```